# Turing off functionality dpending on device iPhone, or iPod touch

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, gps, ipod-touch

I have what i thought was a relatively simple question but i cannot find an answer to it yet. I have an iPhone app that uses GPS on one of its screens. I want to disable this screen using code when the app loads,so disable it when a iPod touch is being used. This is so it can still be useful on a iPod touch as there is a lot of functionality that a iPod touch user can use.

Thanks.

Comment: How is your screen accessed? Are you using a tab bar?

Comment: yeah i'm using a UITabBar, its easy to remove a tab, i just needed the Device logic which has been provided by Aaron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get there with @Aaron's answer, but that's not the way to do it. Use `[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled];` to tell if you can determine the users's location. This is a lot more robust than making decisions based on the device model.

Comment: Thanks kubi, this as you say is a much more robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

to get the device info..

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html

```
NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
```

I think if you are just checking for GPS then you will need to access the CLLocationManager to see if it is on or off

Comment: Thanks, this was greatly helpful.  I did actually search for awhile but my terminology must not of been correct.

Comment: I don't think this is quite correct, even though it gives the same result.  I think you're checking for the sensor that detects if an iPhone is held up to the ear.

Comment: @Darron I believe you are correct, that information should come from the CLLocationManager